# Error adding ViewController to Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I added another ViewController to my Storyboard for my Swift application, and linked one of the buttons from the first ViewController screen to the new screen.  I want to add code to the new View Controller, and created a new class for it but now when I build the app and click the button to go to the new screen, I get an error that says, "Unknown class MyOwnViewController in Interface Builder file." MyOwnViewController is the name of the Class for that screen. Where have I gone wrong? Here's how I've laid out the two classes:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var showOption1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var showOption2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

lazy var buttons: [UIButton] = [self.button1, self.button2]

var voteCount: PFObject?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
            voteCount1["choices"] = 2
            voteCount1["votes"] = Int()
            voteCount1["votes2"] = Int()
            voteCount1["optionName"] = String()
            voteCount1["optionName2"] = String()
            voteCount1["objectId"] = String()
            voteCount1["pollNumber"] = Int()

            var voteCount2 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount2")
            voteCount2["choices"] = 3
            voteCount2["votes"] = Int()
            voteCount2["votes2"] = Int()
            voteCount2["votes3"] = Int()
            voteCount2["optionName"] = String()
            voteCount2["optionName2"] = String()
            voteCount2["optionName3"] = String()

            var voteCount3 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount3")
            voteCount3["choices"] = 4
            voteCount3["votes"] = Int()
            voteCount3["votes2"] = Int()
            voteCount3["votes3"] = Int()
            voteCount3["votes4"] = Int()
            voteCount3["optionName"] = String()
            voteCount3["optionName2"] = String()
            voteCount3["optionName3"] = String()
            voteCount3["optionName4"] = String()

            var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
            query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
                    query.whereKey("pollNumber", equalTo: randNumber)
                    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            NSLog("%@", error)
                        } else {
                            self.voteCount = voteCount1
                            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
                            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
                            let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
                            let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
                            self.showOption1.text = "\(option1)"
                            self.showOption2.text = "\(option2)"
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    println("error \(error)")
                }
            }

}

@IBOutlet weak var pollResults: UILabel!

@IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    for button in self.buttons {
        button.enabled = false
    }
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            self.voteCount = voteCount1
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults.text = "\(votes)                                                       \(votes2)"
        }
        }
    }

@IBOutlet weak var pollResults2: UILabel!

@IBAction func addVote2(sender: AnyObject) {
    for button in self.buttons {
        button.enabled = false
    }
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            self.voteCount = voteCount1
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes2")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults2.text = "\(votes)                                                       \(votes2)"
        }
        }

}


@IBAction func goPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let segues = ["pushTwo1"]
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(segues.count)))
    let segueName = segues[index]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: self)
}


class MyOwnViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var showOption3: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var showOption4: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
        voteCount1["choices"] = 2
        voteCount1["votes"] = Int()
        voteCount1["votes2"] = Int()
        voteCount1["optionName"] = String()
        voteCount1["optionName2"] = String()
        voteCount1["objectId"] = String()
        voteCount1["pollNumber"] = Int()

        var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
        query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
                query.whereKey("pollNumber", equalTo: randNumber)
                query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        NSLog("%@", error)
                    } else {
                        let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
                        let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
                        let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
                        let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
                        self.showOption3.text = "\(option1)"
                        self.showOption4.text = "\(option2)"
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("error \(error)")
            }
        }


    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'MyOwnViewController' class is nested within the 'ViewController' class. You should select all the code for 'MyOwnViewController', cut it, and paste it into its own file.

Comment: I created a new Swift file and called it 'MyOwnViewController' and added it to the project, cut and pasted all that code into the new file, but I'm still getting the error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".

Comment: Are you still getting the message: "Unknown class MyOwnViewController in Interface Builder file."?  If not, then you are dealing with a different problem (that's good!). So what is the new error message? You should be getting more details than what you stated.

Comment: That's correct, I'm still getting that message.  It also says, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'" for the reason, "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key showOption1.'"

Comment: Open your storyboard, then open the Connections inspector. Select each view controller in your storyboard looking for the one that defines a connection named showOption1. Delete that connection.

Comment: What will I need to do if I actually do want to add IBOutlets in my new view controller? That's what showOption1 was.

Comment: You can add outlets by control dragging from the button (or whatever it is) in the storyboard, to the view controller source file. The only reason I had you remove showOption1 was that it somehow got corrupted in the process of fixing your original problem.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but right when I add the IBOutlet I get the error whenever I build the app.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: How do I remove the connection without disabling the IBOutlet? I still need the IBOutlet to work.